# Reliable Directory.Exists using C#

Tags: c#, io, directory

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx), Directory.Exists can return false negatives (the directory exists, but you can't read it or similar). I was wondering if there's a similar method that, instead of returning true or false, returns something more informative... like "access denied" or maybe "path too long"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object instead.  The constructor should throw exceptions if the path is invalid or if the user does not have access.  You would still have to check if it exists though.

```
try
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    if(di.Exists)
    {
        //The directory exists
    }
    else
    {
        //The path is valid, but does not exist.
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //The path is invalid or user does not have access.
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's true that the `DirectoryInfo` constructor throws exceptions for paths that don't exist or for which you don't have access.  At least, it didn't in a quick test I just ran.  Oh, but I see now that you were talking about a truly invalid path, not one that doesn't exist.  But then what good is the test for the OP?

Comment: @adv12 Check the link to the MSDN documentation.  You still have to check if it exists as I mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I see that the OP wants to catch errors like "path too long," which would get caught by that constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Directory.GetAccessControl()` method which you can use to get listable but unreadable directories:

```
public static bool DirectoryVisible(string path)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
        return true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also utilize the `DirectoryInfo` class. It comes with `Exists` property, and `Attributes` property. If there is an `UnauthorizedAccessException` thrown when you access the `Attributes` property, then it means that you cannot access the directory.

Answer (score 0):

[source](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/55409/Directory-Exists-and-Access-Permissions)

this code can differentiate between if a file actually exists, and if the file does but the user doesn't have access

```
enum ExistState { exist, notExist, inaccessible };

void Check(string name) {
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(name);
    ExistState state = ExistState.exist;
    if (!di.Exists) {
        try {
            if ((int)di.Attributes == -1) {
                state = ExistState.notExist;
            }
        } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
            state = ExistState.inaccessible;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", name, state);
}
```

**explanation from the source**
"The DirectoryInfo.Attributes property is incorrectly documented and does not raise the FileNotFound or DirectoryNotFound exceptions but instead returns the error value from the underlying win api function, which is 0xFFFFFFFF or -1.

If a path exists but access is disallowed then an attempt to retrieve the attributes will throw an exception.

If the path does not exist then the attributes will be -1."